# Can't get refresh token from microsoft oauth, msal node js library

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to implement sign in with Microsoft using the library `@azure/msal-node`
I was able to receive access token and id token using `authorization_code` flow but not able to get refresh token. I have added the `offline_access` scope as well.

I found one way to solve this using `acquireTokenSilent` but that also didn't work out for me.

**Sign in for the first time**

```
const microsoftAuthConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
      authority: process.env.MICROSOFT_AUTHORITY,
      clientSecret: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
  };

  const msalClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    microsoftAuthConfig
  );

const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    accessType: 'offline',
    responseType: 'code',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:9000/api/auth/microsoft/redirect',
    state: 'sign in',
    scopes: [
      'user.read',
      'openid',
      'profile',
      'email',
      'Calendars.ReadWrite',
      'offline_access',
    ],
    prompt: 'select_account',
  };

msalClient
    .getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters)
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(301).redirect(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
```

Get tokens using code

```
if (req.query.code) {
    const tokenRequest = {
      code: req.query.code,
      accessType: 'offline',
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
      scopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
        'Calendars.ReadWrite',
        'offline_access',
      ],
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:9000/api/auth/microsoft/redirect',
    };

    msalClient
      .acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('\nResponse: \n:', response);
        res.cookie('auth-microsoft', response.idToken, {
          httpOnly: true,
        });
        return res.status(301).redirect('http://localhost:3000');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // res.status(500).send(error);
      });
  }
```

After this, I am getting access token and id token but not refresh token.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It stores the refresh token in token cache, you can get refresh token from token cache.

```
    const tokenCache = await cca.getTokenCache().serialize();
    const refreshTokenObject = JSON.parse(tokenCache).RefreshToken;
    const refreshToken =
        refreshTokenObject[Object.keys(refreshTokenObject)[0]].secret;
```